# grails - setting up a one to many to one relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
class Invoice {
   static hasMany = [invoiceItem: InvoiceItem]
}

class InvoiceItem {
   static belongsTo = [invoice: Invoice, item: Item]
   static constraints = {
       invoice(nullable: false)
       item(nullable: false)
   }
}

class Item {
   String name
   static hasMany = [invoiceItem: InvoiceItem]
}
```

Let's say I already have an Invoice created, I'm not sure how to create a new item and add it to the Invoice.

I was thinking:

```
Item item1 = new Item(name: "Banana")
InvoiceItem ii = new InvoiceItem(item_id: item1.id)
invoice.addToInvoiceItem(ii);
```

but that doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you wan to setup one to many r/ship?

Comment: There should only be one Invoice and one Item but many InvoiceItems. So it should be a one to many (Invoice, InvoiceItem) and a many to one (InvoiceItem - Item) relationship.

Comment: Forget the invoiceitem table because hibernate will create that for you. or you want to do something special with it?

Comment: Yea can you post this as an answer. I finally figured that out but it took a while. Expand on this explanation and post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really understand your comment *"There should only be one Invoice and one Item but many InvoiceItems."*.

I dont think that statement is valid because `invoiceitem` table will have two columns ( `item_id` and `invoice_id`) so for one `item` and one `invoice` you will have only one `invoiceitem` row unless you want to have duplicate rows in the `invoiceitem`, hence not valid.

So basically you need the middle table `invoiceitem` means you are having many to many relationship between `invoice` and `item`.

In Grails you do it like this, simple:

```
class Invoice {
   static belongsTo = [item: Item]
   static hasMany = [items: Item]
}


class Item {
   String name
   static belongsTo = [invoice: Invoice]
   static hasMany = [invoices: Invoice]
}
```

You can change the names `items` and `invoices` to whatever you like.

So when you create the above two domain classes hibernate knows it is many to many relationship, it needs ***normalization*** and will automatically create the middle table: `invoiceitem` or `iteminvoice` which will contain invoice_id and item_id.

To add item to invoice:

```
invoiceInstance.addToItems(itemInstance)
```

To add invoice to item:

```
itemInstance.addToInvoices(invoiceInstance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting the `item` property of your `InvoiceItem` directly:

```
Item item1 = new Item(name: "Banana")
InvoiceItem ii = new InvoiceItem(item: item1)
invoice.addToInvoiceItem(ii);
```

or if you prefer:

```
InvoiceItem ii = new InvoiceItem(item: new Item(name: "Banana"))
```

And then make sure you save the changes.